# How to keep Visual studio settings syncronized across multiple machines

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to keep the settings of Visual Studio 2012 including toolbars, installed plugins, etc.. in sync across multiple machines?

Comment: Yes, in Visual Studio 2013, you will get such a feature. You can *log in* to a Visual Studio account with Microsoft, and then use that account to synchronize settings across all your development machines

Comment: is it possible in VS 2012?

Comment: As I said: it's a **new feature** in Visual Studio **2013** - so no, it's **not possible** in VS 2012 ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new feature that does this in VS2013 but you're asking about VS2012.

The *VSCommands* addin enables [settings synchronization](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features#settings-synchronization):

> VSCommands will export all current Visual Studio settings (except for
>   Window Layouts) to the Sync Directory and will also monitor this
>   directory for changes.

Also settings can be synchronized across different computers by, for example, saving the file in a dropbox folder:

> VSCommands supports settings synchronization to a folder on your local
>   file system, which you can further synchronize with a cloud using file
>   synchronization services such as Dropbox.

And this addin is **free**, but there's also a paid version that enables more features.